# How To Convert Name Of Resources to string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, resources, type-conversion

I need to convert value of `ColumnName` to a `String`

when convert to string return of value `Name` in `Resources`

> Name= Key1    Value ='David'

```
Key1.ToString() ==> "David"
```

I want the returned 'Key1'

Not returned 'David'

Comment: Please, give some code you are tryng

Comment: How about `nameof(Key1)` or `Key1.Name`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the name of the resource:

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;    

string name = GetName(() => Properties.Resources.Key1);


static string GetName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> property)
{
    return (property.Body as MemberExpression).Member.Name;
}
```

This will get you "Key1";